# Although I use custom action bar, default action bar still looks

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am having trouble with action bar. I have created a new layout for my custom action bar and applied it. Custom action bar works fine but when the application is launched, default action bar seems first and then it disappear. I researched but I couldn't find a solution to solve the problem.

Codes of my main activity are like following..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ActionBar myActionbar = getActionBar();
    myActionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
    myActionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    myActionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    myActionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


}
```

and styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="appTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what does the custom layout for the action bar contain?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your styles.xml file in your res/values folder

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme"></style>
    <style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></style>
    <style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></style>
</resources>
```

Add the following code in your styles.xml file in your res/values-v11 folder

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"></style>
    <style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"></style>
    <style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></style>
</resources>
```

Add the following code in your styles.xml file in your res/values-v14 folder

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
    <style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
    <style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></style>
</resources>
```

Finally in your AndroidManifest.xml file add following code to the activity tag of the activity you want no title for or the application tag if you want it to apply to the entire application.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer. When I add NoTitleBar into the AndroidManifest.xml , I am taking NullPointerException due to myActionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

Comment: What is the min-sdk version in Android Manifest file? And can you check using getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar() method.

Comment: Try adding following line `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` before setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example..

First you have to create layout for custom action bar in order define functionality according to your requirement. Here is the xml file...

layout for custom action bar :

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_back_iv"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_margin_ar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/very_small_margin_ar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/up_navigation"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_titleText_tv"
        style="@style/wrapscreen"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/custom_actionbar_back_iv"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/above_medium_text_size" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_goToArchiveActivity_ib"
        style="@style/wrapscreen"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
```

Here goes the implementation..

Define setupactionBar() method in onCreate() method

```
private void setUpActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View customActionBarView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        // this view is used to show tile
        TextView ActivityTitleTV = (TextView) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_titleText_tv);
        ActivityTitleTV.setText(R.string.title_text_archive);

        //this view can be used for back navigation
        ImageView backToRecorderIV = (ImageView) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_back_iv);
        backToRecorderIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        backToRecorderIV.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Another view which has up navigation
        ImageButton goToArchiveActivityIB = (ImageButton) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_goToArchiveActivity_ib);
        goToArchiveActivityIB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

    //listener for back navigation
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.custom_actionbar_back_iv:
                Intent recorder = new Intent(ArchiveActivity.this, RecorderActivity.class);
                startActivity(recorder);
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I did the following for custom action bar.Maybe someone needs it.

I created **custom_actionbar_theme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style
name="CustomActionBarTheme"
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style
name="CustomActionBarStyle"
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
<item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTextColor</item>
</style>


<style name="ActionBarTextColor"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionBarTitleColor</item>
</style>


</resources>
```

I have changed background and title color of the action bar in this xml. Then I changed

```
<application
        ... 
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```